# Setting cells in google sheets as read-only without locking its column width?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Protecting a range in google sheet also locks the cell's column width.  I would like to make a cell read-only but still allow the user to resize the column width if necessary. Is there a way to do this via google scripts?

Comment: I'm so sad this is a thing. Column width is a view implementation detail, not part of the data. It should be changeable by anyone with read-only. Unfortunately I don't think google allows this

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

You can instruct the readonly user to download the file. They can then change the column width.

It's awful, but it's the best solution I've found.

Answer (score -1):

This is the current feature of [Protect a sheet or range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Once it's protected, it's locked. You'll get this prompt if you try to touch it:

[image]

Comment: correct. so my question: 1) is there a way to modify or bypass this feature via google scripts 2) if not, is there an alternative way to make cells read only such that I am not affecting the user's ability to resize column's width.